# Automake generated makefile has compile command commented out

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I created a autotools project and in Makefile.am I have:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myBin
myBin_SOURCES = src/main.cpp
```

The generated makefile has this target:

```
.cpp.o:
#   $(CXXCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
#   $(am__mv) $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Po
    source='$<' object='$@' libtool=no \
    DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) $(CXXDEPMODE) $(depcomp) \
    $(CXXCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $<
```

As you can see, the actual compiler invocation is commented out. Why?

Comment: UPDATE: if I run ./configure with --disable-dependency-tracking, it builds fine.

Comment: The last line of your snippet is the compiler invocation, and it is not commented out!  The comments are there depending on whether or not you invoke with --disable-dependency-tracking so that only one compiler invocation will be executed.

Comment: The last three lines ar just a variable assignment. Look at the slashes at the end of lines 4 and 5.

Comment: The last line (3 lines) are a call of the shell code defined in depcomp with  5 variable assignments (CXXDEPMODE is an assignment of depmode) and the argument which is the compiler invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what dependency tracking is detected/requested at `configure` time, different parts of the compile command will be commented out. Substituting `#` into `Makefile` in strategic places is how automake implements conditionals. Try to find the original lines in `Makefile.in` and have a look.